# Automated Testing for Oracle APEX Web Application

Tags: java, testing, web-applications, oracle-apex

I'm currently working on a new web application and it's being developed using Oracle APEX.  It's basically a ten page wizard-style web form that gets filled out and submitted.  In nearly all cases, only three or four of these pages will be used and the other exist to present special-case information to the user.

Anyway... I'm currently writing a test plan to ensure all the validation and processes are working as expected and I would like to try automating this testing if at all possible.

Does anyone know any good automated testing tools (preferable open source) that I can put to use for this purpose? Also, as it might be relevant, I'm limited to Java and/or APEX for tailoring these tools to meet my testing needs.

Comment: I'd argue that the fact that the app is Oracle/Apex should be irrelevant, so you may get more feedback if you tag it "web application" or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium - http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) with headless driver such as [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit).
Here you can find how to do it for non rails apps like APEX http://github.com/pshapoval/cucumber-norails

Answer (score 1):

Selenium web driver and RSPEC if you want something straightward. I use it in a legacy classic ASP application and used it with Oracle Apex as well. Best to use ruby rather than the Firefox Selenium IDR.

Follow the below steps
Tested with ruby 2.0.0p481

Installed the following gems

childprocess-0.5.3.gem
diff-lcs-1.2.5.gem
ffi-1.0.11.gem
ffi-1.0.11-java.gem
multi_json-1.10.1.gem
rspec-3.0.0.gem
rspec-core-3.0.4.gem
rspec-expectations-3.0.4.gem
rspec-mocks-3.0.4.gem
rspec-support-3.0.4.gem
rubyzip-1.1.6.gem
selenium-webdriver-2.42.0.gem

To install run

gem install selenium-webdriver --local

You will be asked to install dependencies..follow instructions.

To run tests
rspec RecordAdminTests.rb

You will need selenium server running
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar

> require 'rubygems' require "selenium-webdriver" require "rspec"
>
> describe "Admin ABC" do
>
> before(:each) do        @vcntPg = 20    end
>
> before(:all) do         @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox      @wait
>   = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)       @driver.navigate.to "whateverurl"                   end
>
> after(:all) do          @driver.quit    end
>             describe "Admin Project/User/Events" do
>                 it "Should Edit CDE" do
>
> ```
>               @wait.until {
>                   @driver.find_element(:css ,"a[href*='Home.asp?GroupId=2']")
>               }
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

Answer (score 1):

JMeter can also be used, particularly for load testing. Chris Muir has a good breakdown here
http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/configuring-apache-jmeter-for-apex.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cypress, which has an easy learning curve and interactive test runner right out of the box. This is my goto tool for automated browser testing now.

https://www.cypress.io